# html5 css3 with sharepoint 7

Tags: html, css, sharepoint-2007

Does sharepoint 2007 support html5, and css3 ?
or compatibility of html5 / css3 are based on browser itself?
If html5 tag and css3 are implemented with sharepoint 2007 will sharepoint strip off css3 and html5 tags?

Answer (score 1):

The compatibility is based on the browser itself. If you want to see it working, create a content editor web part, throw the following code in it and try to open the page in IE8 and Chrome. Chrome will render the canvas normally, and IE will display the message inside the tag.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2010 does not support CSS3 so I'm sure 2007 isn't going to support it either. Will 2013 support CSS3?  Who knows. Probably not even Microsoft knows this.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5/CSS3 support is related to browser. In share point you need to add HTML5 doctype if you want your webspage to be rendered in HTML5, However if your browser supports HTML5/CSS3 then you will be able to make it work.

HTML5 Doctype :